# How do you export an MPS file from ortools?

Tags: python, or-tools

Take the example SCIP code for ortools:

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp
solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('SCIP')

infinity = solver.infinity()
# x and y are integer non-negative variables.
x = solver.IntVar(0.0, infinity, 'x')
y = solver.IntVar(0.0, infinity, 'y')

print('Number of variables =', solver.NumVariables())

# x + 7 * y <= 17.5.
solver.Add(x + 7 * y <= 17.5)

# x <= 3.5.
solver.Add(x <= 3.5)

print('Number of constraints =', solver.NumConstraints())

# Maximize x + 10 * y.
solver.Maximize(x + 10 * y)
```

I would like to export this as an MPS file.  I can see

```
solver.ExportModelAsMpsFormat
```

exists but the only documentation I can find says

```
Signature: solver.ExportModelAsMpsFormat(fixed_format: 'bool', obfuscated: 'bool') -> 'std::string'
Docstring: <no docstring>
File:      c:\users\csxrc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ortools\linear_solver\pywraplp.py
Type:      method
```

I don't understand how to use it. For example how to specify the file name.

If I just wanted to save the model as an MPS file called "test.mps", say, what should I do?

**Update**

@Krerkkiat Chusap suggests calling the function to create a string that can be written separately. If I do

```
output_string = solver.ExportModelAsMpsFormat()
```

I get

```
TypeError: ExportModelAsMpsFormat() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'fixed_format' and 'obfuscated'
```

It seems both those arguments are Booleans. What do they signify?

Comment: if you call the method, it should give you the string content that you can then write to a file no?

Comment: @KrerkkiatChusap That's a good idea. If I do that I get `TypeError: ExportModelAsMpsFormat() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'fixed_format' and 'obfuscated'` I will update the question.

Comment: `obfuscated` in general mean to make it unreadable, so it should be false. I tried passing both true and false to the `fixed_format`, but nothing really change.

Comment: from [C++ implementation](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/49b6301e1e1e231d654d79b6032e79809868a70e/ortools/linear_solver/linear_solver.cc#L1705), `fixed_format` doesn't seem to be used ...

Comment: @KrerkkiatChusap Thanks! Could you add an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [C++ implementation](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/49b6301e1e1e231d654d79b6032e79809868a70e/ortools/linear_solver/linear_solver.cc#L1705) the `fixed_format` does not seem to be used, so passing `False` or `True` should be okay.

For `obfuscated`, it usually mean make something hard to read, so make sense to keep it as `False`.

```py
with open("test.mps", "w") as out_f:
    mps_text = solver.ExportModelAsMpsFormat(fixed_format=False, obfuscated=False)
    out_f.write(mps_text)
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what obfuscated is doing. If you run my code with obfuscated=True you seem to get a less obfuscated output. It gives you columns names such as C1 instead of auto_c_000000001.

Comment: That is because when you call `solver.Add(x + 7 * y <= 17.5)`, `name` is not given to the constraint. The exporter then use the auto-generated name for these unnamed constraints (hence the prefix `auto`). Instead if you call `solver.Add(x + 7 * y <= 17.5, name="my_eqn_1")`, you will see the different between `obfuscated=False` and `obfuscated=True`.

Comment: However, if the name is too long, the library [fall back to obfuscated name](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/86d4c543f717fa8716a9d66c25143660668bf825/ortools/linear_solver/model_exporter.cc#L107)